# ActiveRecord BelongsToAssociation sometimes not resolving to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

So, I've got a couple of models in Rails 2.3.11:

```
class RememberToken < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :remember_tokens
    ...
end
```

And in a controller, I do:

```
tok = RememberToken.find_by_token(token_str)
if tok
    u = tok.user
    ...
end
```

When I go to do something with u, it turns out it's an instance of `ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation`, not `ActiveRecord::Base`.

When I change the code to:

```
u = User.find(tok.user_id)
```

all works well. But this is not Best Practices in Rails-land.

Even more frustratingly, the first example only fails in my controller -- doing the same in script/console works fine.

I suspect that this behavior started when we upgraded Rails from 2.3.8 to 2.3.11, but it's hard to know for certain.

I'm completely baffled by this behavior -- any suggestions?

Comment: I think we are missing a piece of code here, could you provide more detailed code.

My initial hunch is some sort of typo